# Memory management - Does addwidget assign a parent

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qlabel, qlayout

Say I have something like this

```
void someClass::start()
{
    QLabel* sb = new QLabel();
    sb->setText("Hello World");
    ui.verticalLayout->addWidget(sb);
}
```

Does addWidget make sb a child of someClass so that when I delete someClass sb is also deleted ? If this is true how do I know which methods in general assign parents to an object ?

Comment: In addition to the Violet's useful answer, you can always check yourself whether if a QObject has a parent, but calling the `parent()` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html:

> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. The layout will automatically reparent
>   the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are children of
>   the widget on which the layout is installed.

Comment: Updated link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts